# Was there a Muggle counterpart for the First Wizarding War?

Tags: harry-potter

We've established than Grindewald's antics were related to World War 2, and that JKR likes to tie Wizarding events to Muggle events.

Was the First Wizarding War meant to tie into any wars, conflicts or events in the late 70s/early 80s?

Comment: Wasn't the IRA in the late 70's and early 80's? I don't really know much British history but that certainly comes to mind.

Comment: History is not my forte. I did as little as possible to get a passing grade in those classes!

Comment: *"The Ministry of Magic's in disarray, they don't know what to do, they're trying to keep everything hidden from the Muggles, but meanwhile, Muggles are dying too. Terror everywhere… panic… confusion… that's how it used to be."*"

Comment: @Richard Always assumed than just meant Death Eaters were killing Muggles. Like with the bridge destruction in Second Wizarding War.

Comment: @Probst the IRA was from 20s to 1990s but they really ramped it up in the 70s and 80s

Comment: @Probst Nope. Even so in 1996 there was the infamous bombing of Manchester; the fact nobody was injured when you see the aftermath is astounding. Then you do have however Sinn Féin and dissidents. But the IRA actually started out with good intention and then turned to thugs. Btw you have the Provisional, Real, Continuity (or was it continual?) and various others: pIRA, rIRA, cIRA, etc.

Comment: As for the question itself: Rowling does note in her own writing on Pottermore that there was sort of involvement with wizards and the First World War though I can't remember specifics. Not sure that matters to the question but as an aside...

Comment: This could I suppose be a 'supplementary answer' but it's short enough where I'll make it a comment; according to Rowling as far as the First World War: **Archer Evermonde** *1912 - 1923* 'In post during the Muggle First World War, Evermonde passed emergency legislation forbidding witches and wizards to get involved, lest they risk mass infractions of the International Statute of Secrecy. Thousands defied him, aiding Muggles where they could.' So there are cases where wizards/witches will help with Muggle wars but I'd say more so they leave Muggles to themselves; w/persecution fair enough.

Comment: Then post First World War pre Second World War: **Hector Fawley**
*1925 - 1939* 'Undoubtedly voted in because of his marked difference to McLaird, the ebullient and flamboyant Fawley did not take sufficiently seriously the threat presented to the world wizarding community by Gellert Grindelwald. He paid with his job.'

Comment: And finally during the Second World War as well as the few years after: **Leonard Spencer-Moon** *1939 - 1948* 'A sound Minister who rose through the ranks from being tea-boy in the Department of Magical Accidents and Catastrophes. Oversaw a great period of international wizarding and Muggle conflict. Enjoyed a good working relationship with Winston Churchill.' So it seems to me that they might have at least corresponded on the Second World War but it's also known that Grindelwald was rampant at that time until Dumbledore confronted him.

Answer (score 6):

Muggles were indeed caught up in the conflict. The Ministry attempted to cover up what was happening and while they were wholly successful in hiding the fact that magic was involved, they couldn't hide the deaths and collateral damage.

> *"The Ministry of Magic's in disarray, they don't know what to do, they're trying to keep everything hidden from the Muggles, but **meanwhile, Muggles are dying too. Terror everywhere**...panic...confusion...that's how it used to be.""*
>
> <sup><sub>[Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/without-a-trial)</sub></sup>

Since we know from the account of the Second Wizard War that magical conflicts can be [messy](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Brockdale_Bridge) and [indiscriminate](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Millennium_Bridge), the most obvious candidate for the MoM to use as a cover would be **the bombing campaign conducted by the IRA in the [late 1970s and early 1980s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_terrorist_incidents_in_Great_Britain#1970s)**. Since this involved a considerable number of terror attacks, largely focused on London and the South of England (where there appears to be a concentration of wizards), it would provide an excellent opportunity to hide any wizard violence that resulted in blast damage or incidental muggle deaths and injuries.

There was also a dramatic uptick of [terrorism around the world](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_terrorism#Late_20th_century) in this period, again, various world ministries could well have been using these as a smokescreen.

Comment: Pre-emptive warning. If you want to talk Harry Potter, please feel free to do so. If you want to discuss the IRA, take it elsewhere.

Comment: So I didn't know IRA by the acronym. I looked it up and found there's something called "the Troubles" that covers all the IRA and similar organizations conflicts. That seems like a likely counterpart, especially since JKR would've old enough to know what was going on. I wonder if she's ever talked about it?

Comment: @CreationEdge - She would have most certainly been aware of it. She was living and working in London in the late 1980s and early 1990s at a time when the IRA were especially active.

Comment: An interesting follow-up question would be: did the Death Eaters *directly* use the IRA, e.g. by Imperiusing its members, or was the IRA more like a smokescreen, i.e. simply an excuse? It is often implied that Grindelwald somehow used the Nazis in order to conquer Europe, and I wonder if something similar happened during the 1st Wizarding War.